# Thank You page redirection after form submission

Tags: php, ajax, forms, redirect

I need to redirect to a thank-you page after the user submits a form. I have search and tried many things and the result is always the same, the mail server receive the message but the browser doesn't go to another page and neither clean the form.

So the index.html have this form:

```
<form action="process.php" id="contact-form" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-name" class="sr-only">Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-name" name="form-name" placeholder="Nombre" required>
        </div>
        <div class="space-10"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="form-email" name="form-email" placeholder="Email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="space-10"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-subject" class="sr-only">Asunto</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-subject" name="form-subject" placeholder="Asunto" required>
        </div>
        <div class="space-10"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="form-message" class="sr-only">comment</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" id="form-message" name="form-message" placeholder="Mensaje" required></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="space-10"></div>
        <button class="btn btn-link no-round text-uppercase" type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And process.php have this:

```
<?php
// Configure your Subject Prefix and Recipient here
$subjectPrefix = 'Consulta EMPRENDE';
$emailTo       = 'emprende@eibanezyasociados.com';
$errors = array(); // array to hold validation errors
$data   = array(); // array to pass back data
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $name    = stripslashes(trim($_POST['name']));
    $email   = stripslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
    $subject = stripslashes(trim($_POST['subject']));
    $message = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
if (empty($name)) {
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';
}
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errors['email'] = 'Email is invalid.';
}
if (empty($subject)) {
    $errors['subject'] = 'Subject is required.';
}
if (empty($message)) {
    $errors['message'] = 'Message is required.';
}
// if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean or false
if (!empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {
    $subject = "$subjectPrefix $subject";
    $body    = '
    <strong>Nombre: </strong>'.$name.'<br />
    <strong>Email: </strong>'.$email.'<br />
    <strong>Mensaje: </strong>'.nl2br($message).'<br />
    ';
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.1" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Date: " . date('r', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . '@' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '>' . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "From: " . "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($name)."?=" . "<$email>" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $emailTo" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "X-Originating-IP: " . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . PHP_EOL;
    mail($emailTo, "=?utf-8?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=", $body, $headers);
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Muchas Gracias. Su mensaje se envió con éxito. Estudiaremos su propuesta a la mayor brevedad posible y contactaremos con usted con la solución que más se ajuste a sus necesidades.';
}
// return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);
```

}

So I've tried commenting the last line and writing this instead:

```
// return all our data to an AJAX call
/*echo json_encode($data);*/

//redirection
header("Location:http://www.emprende.eibanezyasociados.com/gracias.html");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: try this
`ob_start();
       header("Location: http://www.emprende.eibanezyasociados.com/gracias.html");
       exit();`

Answer (score 0):

Having taken a look at your actual website it would appear that you are using an `$.ajax` post request, next time please add that to your question.

You can not redirect the page using PHP when you are using jQuery to post the form, you have to return JSON data i.e `json_encode($data)` from your PHP file `process.php`

Pass the JSON response using `JSON.Parse(data)`, check if the `data['success']` is true, if so you redirect the page using javascript `window.location = "http://www.emprende.eibanezyasociados.com/gracias.html";`

So your Javascript file that you are using to post the form `contact-form.js` should look like:

```
(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
    'use strict';

    var $form = $('#contact-form');

    $form.submit(function (e) {
        // remove the error class
        $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
        $('.help-block').remove();

        // get the form data
        var formData = {
            'name' : $('input[name="form-name"]').val(),
            'email' : $('input[name="form-email"]').val(),
            'subject' : $('input[name="form-subject"]').val(),
            'message' : $('textarea[name="form-message"]').val()
        };

        // process the form
        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'process.php',
            data : formData,
            dataType : 'json',
            encode : true
        }).done(function (data) {
            // handle errors
            if (!data.success) {
                if (data.errors.name) {
                    $('#name-field').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#name-field').find('.col-lg-10').append('<span class="help-block">' + data.errors.name + '</span>');
                }

                if (data.errors.email) {
                    $('#email-field').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#email-field').find('.col-lg-10').append('<span class="help-block">' + data.errors.email + '</span>');
                }

                if (data.errors.subject) {
                    $('#subject-field').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#subject-field').find('.col-lg-10').append('<span class="help-block">' + data.errors.subject + '</span>');
                }

                if (data.errors.message) {
                    $('#message-field').addClass('has-error');
                    $('#message-field').find('.col-lg-10').append('<span class="help-block">' + data.errors.message + '</span>');
                }
            } else {
                // display success message
                $form.html('<div class="alert alert-success">' + data.message + '</div>');
                window.location = "http://www.emprende.eibanezyasociados.com/gracias.html";
            }
        }).fail(function (data) {
            // for debug
            console.log(data)
        });

        e.preventDefault();
    });
}(jQuery, window, document));
```

And your PHP file `process.php` should look like:

```
<?php
// Configure your Subject Prefix and Recipient here
$subjectPrefix = 'Consulta EMPRENDE';
$emailTo       = 'emprende@eibanezyasociados.com';
$errors = array(); // array to hold validation errors
$data   = array(); // array to pass back data
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $name    = stripslashes(trim($_POST['name']));
    $email   = stripslashes(trim($_POST['email']));
    $subject = stripslashes(trim($_POST['subject']));
    $message = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));
if (empty($name)) {
    $errors['name'] = 'Name is required.';
}
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errors['email'] = 'Email is invalid.';
}
if (empty($subject)) {
    $errors['subject'] = 'Subject is required.';
}
if (empty($message)) {
    $errors['message'] = 'Message is required.';
}
// if there are any errors in our errors array, return a success boolean or false
if (!empty($errors)) {
    $data['success'] = false;
    $data['errors']  = $errors;
} else {
    $subject = "$subjectPrefix $subject";
    $body    = '
    <strong>Nombre: </strong>'.$name.'<br />
    <strong>Email: </strong>'.$email.'<br />
    <strong>Mensaje: </strong>'.nl2br($message).'<br />
    ';
    $headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.1" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Date: " . date('r', $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Message-ID: <" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] . md5($_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']) . '@' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '>' . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "From: " . "=?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($name)."?=" . "<$email>" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $emailTo" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/". phpversion() . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= "X-Originating-IP: " . $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] . PHP_EOL;
    mail($emailTo, "=?utf-8?B?" . base64_encode($subject) . "?=", $body, $headers);
    $data['success'] = true;
    $data['message'] = 'Muchas Gracias. Su mensaje se envió con éxito. Estudiaremos su propuesta a la mayor brevedad posible y contactaremos con usted con la solución que más se ajuste a sus necesidades.';
}
// return all our data to an AJAX call
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: Yes, follow and read the http requests/responses from your ajax calls.